Is it natural to say "Could you come again?" or just "Come again?"?
In Oxford Dictionary,

come again?: ​(informal) used to ask somebody to repeat something
‘She's an entomologist.’ ‘Come again?’ ‘An entomologist—she studies
insects.’

My question is that, do you always say just "come again?" even to older people or ones that you needs to show respect for.
For example,

Grandpa: ......
Grandchild: Come again?

I feel like "Could you come again?" or "Come again, please" sounds unnatural.
It seems like "Come again?" is only used for peers or when you talk to a younger person.
Most dictionaries just say "Come again?" without "please" or "Could".

This is two different questions! Yes, "Come again" is informal. If you wanted to tell someone politely that you didn't catch what they said, you would say "I beg your pardon?" (or just "Pardon?"), "What did you say?" or "Excuse me?"

I can answer your question about forms of address, but it needs to be posted as a separate question.

@KateBunting, done as your request. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/355391/is-it-polite-to-call-your-grandma-by-her-first-name

The clearest question would be: “Can you repeat that?”  It has no connotations of surprise or anger like: “I beg your pardon” might have.
