Is it impolite to call your Grandma by her first name?
I think there is disagreement among native English speakers about polite expression.
One native English speaker says you can call your grandma by her first name. That is not rude, and it is normal to say that. I even heard some Australian people say like that quite often.
For example, a grandma's name is Nola.

Grandchild:  Nola, there is someone looking for you.

In my Asian culture, that is really rude. A better version is "Grandma, there is someone looking for you" . I heard many Australian people say that. Not sure how people think about it in Britain and America.
But, in a movie, I have seen people saying something like this:

Child to his mom: Nola (grandma's name) has been taken to hospital.
Mom: say "Grandma" please.

It's good to say "Grandma Nola" but not "Nola" alone.
That implies calling your grandma by her first name alone is not polite.
Is it impolite to call your Grandma by her first name?

My children called one grandmother 'Granny Mary' and the other 'Granny Helen'. You question cannot be answered properly. The answer is a matter of opinion.

@MichaelHarvey, 'Granny Mary' is perfectly polite. But if your children say "Mary won't come with us"???

In the US, it entirely depends on the family and individual preferences. I would say, as a rule, that it's seen as more rude to refer to someone in a way other than the one they want to be called. The US has such a mix of cultures, that there is very little consistency on this.

In my family, children were taught to say "Grandma [Name]" or Grandpa [Nickname]." So for example, my grandmother was Nyla, and her grandkids all called her Grandma Ny. But in my family, as an adult, the title was commonly dropped. So her adult grandchildren would simply call her "Nyla."
This rule carries through in my family for aunts and uncles. So as a child I was taught to say "Uncle Matt" but now that I'm an adult, it's expected that I will simply call him "Matt" most of the time. As an adult, using "Uncle Matt" emphasizes the age difference so is used in only specific situations.

Many families in the US use familial nicknames for grandparents specifically. My partner's grandmother was referred to as "Mimi" once she became a grandma, and all the adults around her grandchild would call her that.

I'm from the UK.  It's not common to call your grandparents or even your parents by their first names in the UK. I also have some Australian relatives, and I think it's the same in Australia.  Never heard any of them do this.  Of course that doesn't mean there aren't exceptions.  It would be unusual at the very least. Perhaps a mistake a very young child just learning to speak might make, and parents would likely correct them.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not ultimately about the English language but culture, and conventions may vary across (the very many) English-speaking cultures.

I've voted to reopen this question.  The question asks about whether a certain form of address is polite.  ELL has scores of questions about what words or phrases are polite.  How is this question different?  And while I agree with others here who say that there is much variation in usage, I don't think that makes this question unanswerable - I think that is the answer.  It's not necessarily rude.  As opposed to forms of address which would generally be considered impolite like geezer, codger, old fart, etc.

@Juhasz - whether a form of address is 'polite' is both a matter of opinion and also (as in this case) very much location and culture dependent, either of which is a powerful closure reason. Taken together, the case for downvoting and closure is overwhelming.

In Western countries it is usual to address family members of the generations above yours by their relationship to you (Mother, Grandfather) or a nickname based on it (Mummy, Grandpa). When I was growing up in England in the 1950s and 60s, it was considered bad manners for a child to address any adult by their given name alone; we were taught to call family friends "Auntie Mary" or "Uncle John", otherwise it was "Mr" or "Mrs Smith. It was very unusual for children to be brought up to call their parents by their given names, though it did occasionally happen. My own cousin brought up his children to call their real aunt and uncle by their names without the prefix.
Nowadays it's much less formal - even quite small children address adults by their given name - but it's still unusual to do this with parents and grandparents. I don't know whether this is more common in Australia. It's not 'rude' if that's what you were brought up to do.

Perhaps some confusion comes from the fact that, traditionally, many kids have had only one of each gendered parental role, but two of each gendered grandparent role. They may distinguish between "Grandma" and "Grannie" or other nicknames, but this is also the main reason first names come into play, albeit usually with titles ("Grandma Sue"). There may be any number of aunts and uncles, so in fact "Aunt Sue" is the default.

And of course the diversity of modern families is one of the things that can drive first name usage: If your biological dad is "Dad," how do you address your stepdad? What of your now three grandmothers? If a kid has two dads, are they both "Dad?" What about adoption?

@AndyBonner - I have heard of same-sex couples where one is 'Dad' and the other is 'Poppa', or both are Dad and it seems to work fine, Also Dad and Matt. Also I know of some children who called their mother's partner 'Om' which was short for Other Mother.
